# How do i bind and populate data at pageload using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues binding the results of my drop-down filter ($scope.selectedOperation.OP_NAME) to the web service so that results are displayed at page load. I keep getting an error that says "Cannot read property OP_NAME of undefined." even though when I log results to console, everything looks correct. Please help!

```
var headcountsApp = angular.module('headcountsApp', []);

headcountsApp.controller('headcountsController', ['$scope', '$http', 
function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.selectOperations = [];;

  //Data for drop-down filters
  $scope.getOpFilter = function() {
    var dtaArray = {};
    $http.post("/services/SA.svc/getOpName", dtaArray).then(function onSuccess(response) {
      $scope.opFilter = JSON.parse(response.data.getOpNameResult);

      angular.forEach($scope.opFilter, function(value, key) {
        $scope.selectOperations.push(value);
      });
      $scope.selectedOperation = $scope.selectOperations[0];
    });
  };

  $scope.corpArray = [];

  $scope.getCorp = function() {
    var dtaArray = {};
    dtaArray.OP_NAME = $scope.selectedOperation.OP_NAME;

    var dtaJson = JSON.stringify(dtaArray);

    $http.post("/services/SA.svc/getCorpHeadCounts",
      dtaArray).then(function onSuccess(response) {
      $scope.corporateSummary =
        JSON.parse(response.data.getCorpHeadCountsResult);

      angular.forEach($scope.corporateSummary, function(value, key) {
        $scope.corpArray.push(value);
      });
    });
  };
  angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    $scope.getOpFilter();
    $scope.getCorp();
  });
}]);
```

Comment: you need to have something there...

Comment: something where?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code in debug.  If so, I'd bet you'll see that  $scope.getCorp() is called before $scope.selectedOperation is set.  It's because the promise ($http) in $scope.getOpFilter() won't be fulfilled before $scope.getCorp() is called.  You need to search this site for promise chaining and/or $q.all().  These topics have been covered many times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove last line angular.element(document).ready(function() { } call $scope.getOpFilter() after getOpFilter function and $scope.getCorp() after getCorp function.